# Dynamic Cassandra queries

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have a messenger application with a history page, on which you can see your sent and received messages.

Since the amount of messages has lowered my performance I have been thinking about using Cassandra.

After researching on the topic of Cassandra, I found out that you have to build tables to satisfy your queries.

Now the problem: on the history page you can use x amount of different filters at the same time. e.g filter by date,receiver and sender.

If I were to use Cassandra, would I need to create a table for every combination of these filters?
Or is this a bad use case for Cassandra in general? 
If so, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a SELECT statement.
You should definately have a look into CQL (Cassandra Query Language).
While CQL and SQL share a similar syntax queries are a lot different.
The reasons for these differences is the fact that Cassandra is dealing with distributed data and aims to prevent inefficient queries.

See [this link](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) for reference. It shows queries you can or cannot do.

Comment: According to the article the attribute of the where clause needs to either have an index or be part of a primary key. In my use case that would mean all attribute of the table either have an index or are part of the PK.  or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: The primary key is a combination between the partition key column and the clustering column.
Clustering is very important for efficient retreiving of rows